# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Закрыть приложение без вызова диалогового окна

Tags: c#, ms-word

Создал экземпляры классов для формирования документов в Word

```
app = new Word.Application();
doc = app.Documents.Add(ref path);
```

После произведения всех необходимых операций, сохраняю документ в формате PDF и закрываю приложение

```
 //Save as PDF
string filename = "Отчёт. " + FIO + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", "-") + ".pdf";
            this.app.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(filename, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, true, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen,
                WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, true, true,
                WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks, true, true, false);

//Close document
app.Visible = false;
app.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = false;
app.Documents.Close();
app.Quit();
doc = null;
app = null;
GC.Collect();
```

В конце у меня открывается сформированный PDF-документ - тут всё по плану.
А также открывается диалоговое окно для сохранения документа Word. Если нажать отмена, то вылетает исключение и крашится консольное приложение. Хотелось бы избежать этого диалогового окна и запретить его открывать. Как это сделать?

Comment: [How to NOT save documents using microsoft.office.interop.word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15231923/312041)

Comment: Всё хорошо. Однако, одна заминка. Процесс WINWORD.EXE не киляется и остаётся в пуле.

Comment: я не понимаю ваш сленг. Вам надо было, чтобы окошко не поялялось - я вам скинул точно такой же вопрос с принятым ответом.

Comment: Простите за сленг. Если несколько раз запустить формирование отчёта, то в процессах зависают экземпляры WINWORD.EXE. Хотелось бы, чтобы вместе с закрытием приложения закрывались и эти процессы.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена следующим образом - после сохранения PDF-документа вставить код:

```
//Close document
object saveOption = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
object originalFormat = Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
object routeDocument = false;
doc.Close(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
app.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
app.Quit();
doc = null;
app = null;
GC.Collect();
```

В итоге не появляется диалоговое окно и не остаётся зависшего процесса WINWORD.EXE